# Python BeautifulSoup 4 new_tag: Dont alphabetize the attributes

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

When I create a new tag with a dict of attributes like this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(body, 'html.parser')

my_attrs = {
   'async': '',
   'src': 'https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js',
   'charset': 'utf-8',
}
soup.new_tag('script', attrs=my_attrs)
```

the tag that gets created is this

```
<script async="" charset="utf-8" src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js">
```

I want the attributes to appear in the exact order that the dictionary has them like this:

```
<script async="" src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8">
```

Is this possible using BeautifulSoup or will I have to use regex to make this happen?

Comment: I get in the same order as in the dictionary upon replicating this.

Comment: I am using bs4 `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` in case that makes a difference

Answer (score 1):

Beautiful Soup sorts the attributes in every tag by default. In the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), there's an example, how you can turn it off:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.formatter import HTMLFormatter
from collections import OrderedDict

body = ''
soup = BeautifulSoup(body, 'html.parser')

my_attrs = OrderedDict([
   ('async', ''),
   ('src', 'https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js'),
   ('charset', 'utf-8'),
])

class UnsortedAttributes(HTMLFormatter):
    def attributes(self, tag):
        for k, v in tag.attrs.items():
            # here you can filter attributes:
            # if k == 'm':
            #     continue
            yield k, v

t = soup.new_tag('script', **my_attrs)
print(t.encode(formatter=UnsortedAttributes()).decode())
```

Prints:

```
<script async="" src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```